# FxCop Code analysis error for Provider Hosted App

Tags: security, provider-hosted-app

I am running FxCop tool on my provider hosted app. But it is giving an error in web.config file like

> CA3116 DenyUnauthorizedUsers You are explicitly allowing all
>   authenticated users for whom no valid  rule is specified. If
>   this is not your intent, terminate the authorization rules list using
>    to deny everyone for whom no explicit  rule
>   exists

Currently in web.config following are the configurations:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

I have tried different combinations in web.config file, but nothing worked out. How to get rid of this error.